# How to code the toggle script to only affect one part of the site?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

In other words, I'd like the toggle code to work only on the part of the site where it's called. Currently, since there are classes involved, the script fires on all (similar) classes (when the `.showAll` is clicked all `.newsTexCont` get `.openNewsText`).

How to write the code without `id`'s, and keep the way parts can be repeated with classes?

```js
$('.showAll').click(function() {
  $('.newsTextCont').toggleClass("openNewsText");
  $(this).toggleClass('newsToggle');
});
```

```css
.newsTitle {
  align-self: stretch;
  color: black;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Lato;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 38px;
  word-wrap: break-word
}

.newsTextCont {
  align-self: stretch;
  height: 124px;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  display: flex
}

.newsTextInner {
  align-self: stretch;
  height: 100px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Lato;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 24px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.newsTextInner::after {
  content: "...";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 4px;
}

.openNewsText .newsTextInner::after {
  content: none;
}

.newsTextCont.openNewsText,
.openNewsText .newsTextInner {
  height: auto;
}

.showAll {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.showAll:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.showAll::after {
  content: "";
  background: url(svg/footerChevron.svg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: all 1s;
  width: 12px;
  height: 7px;
  position: relative;
  left: 7px;
  bottom: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.showAll.newsToggle::after {
  content: "";
  background: url(svg/footerChevron.svg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  transition: all 1s;
  width: 12px;
  height: 7px;
  position: relative;
  left: 7px;
  bottom: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="sec_pub">
  <div class="innerWrap newsWrap">
    <div class="newsCont">
      <div class="newsLeftCont">
        <div class="newsLeftContInner">
          <div class="newsDate">28. September 2022.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="newsMiddleCont">
        <div class="newsTitle">TITLE</div>
        <div class="newsTextCont">
          <div class="newsTextInner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. In tellus integer feugiat scelerisque varius. Odio tempor orci dapibus ultrices in iaculis. Aliquam sem fringilla ut
            morbi. Est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim cras tincidunt. Mauris ultrices eros in cursus turpis massa tincidunt dui ut. Tortor vitae purus faucibus ornare suspendisse sed nisi. Elit ut aliquam purus sit amet luctus. Feugiat pretium
            nibh ipsum consequat nisl vel. Nulla aliquet enim tortor at auctor. Malesuada bibendum arcu vitae elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed velit. Et malesuada fames ac turpis. Egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta. Tristique magna sit amet
            purus gravida. Amet porttitor eget dolor morbi non arcu risus quis varius. Ornare lectus sit amet est placerat in egestas erat. Faucibus in ornare quam viverra orci sagittis eu. Consequat interdum varius sit amet mattis vulputate enim nulla.</div>
          <div class="showAllCont">
            <div class="showAll" id="showAll">Show all</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="newsImgCont">
          <img class="newsImg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/682x460" />
          <div class="newsImgCredit">&copy; Aliquam ut porttitor leo</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="innerWrap newsWrap">
    <div class="newsCont">
      <div class="newsLeftCont">
        <div class="newsLeftContInner">
          <div class="newsDate">28. September 2022.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="newsMiddleCont">
        <div class="newsTitle">TITLE</div>
        <div class="newsTextCont">
          <div class="newsTextInner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. In tellus integer feugiat scelerisque varius. Odio tempor orci dapibus ultrices in iaculis. Aliquam sem fringilla ut
            morbi. Est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim cras tincidunt. Mauris ultrices eros in cursus turpis massa tincidunt dui ut. Tortor vitae purus faucibus ornare suspendisse sed nisi. Elit ut aliquam purus sit amet luctus. Feugiat pretium
            nibh ipsum consequat nisl vel. Nulla aliquet enim tortor at auctor. Malesuada bibendum arcu vitae elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed velit. Et malesuada fames ac turpis. Egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta. Tristique magna sit amet
            purus gravida. Amet porttitor eget dolor morbi non arcu risus quis varius. Ornare lectus sit amet est placerat in egestas erat. Faucibus in ornare quam viverra orci sagittis eu. Consequat interdum varius sit amet mattis vulputate enim nulla.</div>
          <div class="showAllCont">
            <div class="showAll">Show all</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="newsImgCont">
          <img class="newsImg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/682x460" />
          <div class="newsImgCredit">&copy; Aliquam ut porttitor leo</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="innerWrap newsWrap">
    <div class="newsCont">
      <div class="newsLeftCont">
        <div class="newsLeftContInner">
          <div class="newsDate">28. September 2022.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="newsMiddleCont">
        <div class="newsTitle">TITLE</div>
        <div class="newsTextCont">
          <div class="newsTextInner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. In tellus integer feugiat scelerisque varius. Odio tempor orci dapibus ultrices in iaculis. Aliquam sem fringilla ut
            morbi. Est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim cras tincidunt. Mauris ultrices eros in cursus turpis massa tincidunt dui ut. Tortor vitae purus faucibus ornare suspendisse sed nisi. Elit ut aliquam purus sit amet luctus. Feugiat pretium
            nibh ipsum consequat nisl vel. Nulla aliquet enim tortor at auctor. Malesuada bibendum arcu vitae elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed velit. Et malesuada fames ac turpis. Egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta. Tristique magna sit amet
            purus gravida. Amet porttitor eget dolor morbi non arcu risus quis varius. Ornare lectus sit amet est placerat in egestas erat. Faucibus in ornare quam viverra orci sagittis eu. Consequat interdum varius sit amet mattis vulputate enim nulla.</div>
          <div class="showAllCont">
            <div class="showAll">Show all</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="newsImgCont">
          <img class="newsImg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/682x460" />
          <div class="newsImgCredit">&copy; Aliquam ut porttitor leo</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="innerWrap newsWrap">
    <div class="newsCont">
      <div class="newsLeftCont">
        <div class="newsLeftContInner">
          <div class="newsDate">28. September 2022.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="newsMiddleCont">
        <div class="newsTitle">TITLE</div>
        <div class="newsTextCont">
          <div class="newsTextInner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. In tellus integer feugiat scelerisque varius. Odio tempor orci dapibus ultrices in iaculis. Aliquam sem fringilla ut
            morbi. Est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim cras tincidunt. Mauris ultrices eros in cursus turpis massa tincidunt dui ut. Tortor vitae purus faucibus ornare suspendisse sed nisi. Elit ut aliquam purus sit amet luctus. Feugiat pretium
            nibh ipsum consequat nisl vel. Nulla aliquet enim tortor at auctor. Malesuada bibendum arcu vitae elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed velit. Et malesuada fames ac turpis. Egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta. Tristique magna sit amet
            purus gravida. Amet porttitor eget dolor morbi non arcu risus quis varius. Ornare lectus sit amet est placerat in egestas erat. Faucibus in ornare quam viverra orci sagittis eu. Consequat interdum varius sit amet mattis vulputate enim nulla.</div>
          <div class="showAllCont">
            <div class="showAll">Show all</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="newsImgCont">
          <img class="newsImg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/682x460" />
          <div class="newsImgCredit">&copy; Aliquam ut porttitor leo</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're selecting *all* the `.newsTestCont` elements in the DOM and updating each of them.

To fix the problem you need to traverse the DOM to find only the one related to the `.showAll` button which was clicked. To do that use `this` to get a reference to the button, along with the `closest()` method.

Change this:

```
$('.newsTextCont').toggleClass("openNewsText");
```

To this:

```
$(this).closest('.newsTextCont').toggleClass("openNewsText");
```

Here's a working example:

```js
$('.showAll').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.newsTextCont').toggleClass("openNewsText");
  $(this).toggleClass('newsToggle');
});
```

```css
.newsTitle {
  align-self: stretch;
  color: black;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Lato;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 38px;
  word-wrap: break-word
}

.newsTextCont {
  align-self: stretch;
  height: 124px;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  display: flex
}

.newsTextInner {
  align-self: stretch;
  height: 100px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Lato;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 24px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.newsTextInner::after {
  content: "...";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 4px;
}

.openNewsText .newsTextInner::after {
  content: none;
}

.newsTextCont.openNewsText,
.openNewsText .newsTextInner {
  height: auto;
}

.showAll {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.showAll:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.showAll::after {
  content: "";
  background: url(svg/footerChevron.svg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: all 1s;
  width: 12px;
  height: 7px;
  position: relative;
  left: 7px;
  bottom: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.showAll.newsToggle::after {
  content: "";
  background: url(svg/footerChevron.svg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  transition: all 1s;
  width: 12px;
  height: 7px;
  position: relative;
  left: 7px;
  bottom: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="sec_pub">
  <div class="innerWrap newsWrap">
    <div class="newsCont">
      <div class="newsLeftCont">
        <div class="newsLeftContInner">
          <div class="newsDate">28. September 2022.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="newsMiddleCont">
        <div class="newsTitle">TITLE</div>
        <div class="newsTextCont">
          <div class="newsTextInner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. In tellus integer feugiat scelerisque varius. Odio tempor orci dapibus ultrices in iaculis. Aliquam sem fringilla ut
            morbi. Est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim cras tincidunt. Mauris ultrices eros in cursus turpis massa tincidunt dui ut. Tortor vitae purus faucibus ornare suspendisse sed nisi. Elit ut aliquam purus sit amet luctus. Feugiat pretium
            nibh ipsum consequat nisl vel. Nulla aliquet enim tortor at auctor. Malesuada bibendum arcu vitae elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed velit. Et malesuada fames ac turpis. Egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta. Tristique magna sit amet
            purus gravida. Amet porttitor eget dolor morbi non arcu risus quis varius. Ornare lectus sit amet est placerat in egestas erat. Faucibus in ornare quam viverra orci sagittis eu. Consequat interdum varius sit amet mattis vulputate enim nulla.</div>
          <div class="showAllCont">
            <div class="showAll" id="showAll">Show all</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="newsImgCont">
          <img class="newsImg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/682x460" />
          <div class="newsImgCredit">&copy; Aliquam ut porttitor leo</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="innerWrap newsWrap">
    <div class="newsCont">
      <div class="newsLeftCont">
        <div class="newsLeftContInner">
          <div class="newsDate">28. September 2022.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="newsMiddleCont">
        <div class="newsTitle">The H4H program reached new milestones</div>
        <div class="newsTextCont">
          <div class="newsTextInner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. In tellus integer feugiat scelerisque varius. Odio tempor orci dapibus ultrices in iaculis. Aliquam sem fringilla ut
            morbi. Est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim cras tincidunt. Mauris ultrices eros in cursus turpis massa tincidunt dui ut. Tortor vitae purus faucibus ornare suspendisse sed nisi. Elit ut aliquam purus sit amet luctus. Feugiat pretium
            nibh ipsum consequat nisl vel. Nulla aliquet enim tortor at auctor. Malesuada bibendum arcu vitae elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed velit. Et malesuada fames ac turpis. Egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta. Tristique magna sit amet
            purus gravida. Amet porttitor eget dolor morbi non arcu risus quis varius. Ornare lectus sit amet est placerat in egestas erat. Faucibus in ornare quam viverra orci sagittis eu. Consequat interdum varius sit amet mattis vulputate enim nulla.</div>
          <div class="showAllCont">
            <div class="showAll">Show all</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="newsImgCont">
          <img class="newsImg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/682x460" />
          <div class="newsImgCredit">&copy; Aliquam ut porttitor leo</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="innerWrap newsWrap">
    <div class="newsCont">
      <div class="newsLeftCont">
        <div class="newsLeftContInner">
          <div class="newsDate">28. September 2022.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="newsMiddleCont">
        <div class="newsTitle">The H4H program reached new milestones</div>
        <div class="newsTextCont">
          <div class="newsTextInner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. In tellus integer feugiat scelerisque varius. Odio tempor orci dapibus ultrices in iaculis. Aliquam sem fringilla ut
            morbi. Est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim cras tincidunt. Mauris ultrices eros in cursus turpis massa tincidunt dui ut. Tortor vitae purus faucibus ornare suspendisse sed nisi. Elit ut aliquam purus sit amet luctus. Feugiat pretium
            nibh ipsum consequat nisl vel. Nulla aliquet enim tortor at auctor. Malesuada bibendum arcu vitae elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed velit. Et malesuada fames ac turpis. Egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta. Tristique magna sit amet
            purus gravida. Amet porttitor eget dolor morbi non arcu risus quis varius. Ornare lectus sit amet est placerat in egestas erat. Faucibus in ornare quam viverra orci sagittis eu. Consequat interdum varius sit amet mattis vulputate enim nulla.</div>
          <div class="showAllCont">
            <div class="showAll">Show all</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="newsImgCont">
          <img class="newsImg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/682x460" />
          <div class="newsImgCredit">&copy; Aliquam ut porttitor leo</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="innerWrap newsWrap">
    <div class="newsCont">
      <div class="newsLeftCont">
        <div class="newsLeftContInner">
          <div class="newsDate">28. September 2022.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="newsMiddleCont">
        <div class="newsTitle">The H4H program reached new milestones</div>
        <div class="newsTextCont">
          <div class="newsTextInner">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. In tellus integer feugiat scelerisque varius. Odio tempor orci dapibus ultrices in iaculis. Aliquam sem fringilla ut
            morbi. Est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim cras tincidunt. Mauris ultrices eros in cursus turpis massa tincidunt dui ut. Tortor vitae purus faucibus ornare suspendisse sed nisi. Elit ut aliquam purus sit amet luctus. Feugiat pretium
            nibh ipsum consequat nisl vel. Nulla aliquet enim tortor at auctor. Malesuada bibendum arcu vitae elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed velit. Et malesuada fames ac turpis. Egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta. Tristique magna sit amet
            purus gravida. Amet porttitor eget dolor morbi non arcu risus quis varius. Ornare lectus sit amet est placerat in egestas erat. Faucibus in ornare quam viverra orci sagittis eu. Consequat interdum varius sit amet mattis vulputate enim nulla.</div>
          <div class="showAllCont">
            <div class="showAll">Show all</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="newsImgCont">
          <img class="newsImg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/682x460" />
          <div class="newsImgCredit">&copy; Aliquam ut porttitor leo</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```